# Change fonts in an SVG file

Tags: css, extjs, svg, fonts, sencha-touch

I've got an SVG file which displays some text, but I can't seem to get the correct font working.. The problem is that even though I declare a @font-face{}, and use it exactly like every tutorial I could find on the web, the SVG does not want to make use of it. I can add custom fonts directly in the `<text font-family="blabla">` if they are installed on the machine, but as I'm using Sencha Touch to build an app for mobile devices, those fonts won't be installed.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? It is the correct url-path to the font btw.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Lager_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 235.1 49.1" enable-background="new 0 0 235.1 49.1" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C2531A" d="M24.5,0h186c13.5,0,24.5,11,24.5,24.5l0,0
    c0,13.5-11,24.5-24.5,24.5h-186C11,49.1,0,38,0,24.5l0,0C0,11,11,0,24.5,0L24.5,0z"/>
<defs>
    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: GothamNarrowBook;
        src: url('../fonts/gothamfont/GothamNarrow-Book.otf');
        }
    </style>
</defs>
<text transform="matrix(1.0034 0 0 1 114.2635 35.8735)" fill="#F0BA9F" font-family="GothamNarrowBook" font-size="30.6347">BOOKS</text>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#EAA888" d="M87.3,35.8h7.9v-6.2h1.3l4,6.2h8.9l-5.1-7.6
    c0.9-0.4,1.7-0.9,2.3-1.5c0.7-0.6,1.2-1.3,1.5-2.1c0.4-0.8,0.6-1.7,0.6-2.7v-0.2c0-1.1-0.2-2.1-0.6-2.9c-0.4-0.8-1-1.6-1.7-2.2
    c-0.9-0.7-2-1.3-3.4-1.7c-1.4-0.4-3.1-0.6-5.1-0.6H87.4h-0.1H71.6h-2.2h-6.1l-2.8,11l-3-11h-8.4l-0.1,0h-3.1l-1.9,9.1l-2.1-9.1h-6.4
    l-2.1,9.1l-1.8-9h-7.9l5.6,21.4h6.9l2.5-9l2.4,9h6.9L51.9,22l4.5,13c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.1
    c-0.3,0-0.8-0.1-1.3-0.3c-0.5-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.8-0.8L50.1,40c1,0.5,2.1,0.9,3.2,1.3c1.1,0.3,2.3,0.5,3.5,0.5c1.1,0,2.1-0.1,3-0.4
    c0.9-0.3,1.6-0.7,2.3-1.3c0.7-0.6,1.2-1.4,1.7-2.3c0.5-0.9,1-2.1,1.4-3.4L69.5,21h7.3l-7.6,9.5v5.4h15.6v-6.5h-5l7.5-9.4V35.8
    L87.3,35.8z M95.2,24.7V20h2.6c0.6,0,1.1,0.1,1.5,0.3c0.4,0.2,0.8,0.4,1,0.8c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.4,1.3v0.2c0,0.5-0.1,0.9-0.4,1.3
    c-0.2,0.3-0.6,0.6-1,0.8c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.3-1.5,0.3H95.2L95.2,24.7z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Most likely a problem with the font file, check that it exists and that it's valid. Also check that the browser you use doesn't block access to it due to security (mostly if you load the svg file locally instead of from a web server). Here are some examples of how to use webfonts in svg files: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/fonts/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there's nothing wrong with the font file.. for instance, I downloaded the zeimusu font from your link and that didn't work either.. I also made sure to have done EXACTLY as you had in your examples.
How exactly do I check that the browser doesn't block access to it? It seems weird, though, as I can be able to use the font if I don't attempt to create via the font-face, and instead just use the machine-installed font.

Comment: Does it fail in all browsers? Can you put the full example online with the font file? Perhaps the font file is being served with an incorrect mimetype? To see if the browser downloads and uses a webfont just open up a web inspector (e.g right-click the page and choose "Inspect element").